# Exercise with vector code snippet, includes for loop

Tags: c++, vector, for-loop

First of all, this is NOT homework. I'm using a book I bought for myself to learn the beginning of C++ at home, and it contains an exercise I'm stuck with. It asks me what is wrong with the following code, but I'm not sure if I'm looking it at the right way.

**These are the exercise and code:**

> Assuming that scores is a vector that holds elements of type int,
>   what's wrong with the following code snippet (meant to increment each
>   element)?
>
> ```
> vector<int>::iterator iter;
> for (iter = scores.begin(); iter != scores.end(); ++iter)
> {
>   iter++;
> }
> ```

My guess is that 'iter++' is injected in the for function AND the for block, which would mean that it would be injected two times and therefor would pass beyond the end of the loop. Is this correct?

Comment: it has a 50% chance of doing a ++ when iter==scores.end(), thus exploding. if there are an even number of ints in the scores, then it won't.  in either case, whatever else is going on in the loop will skip every other item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. The issue with this code is that the iterator is incremented inside the loop, and also after the body of the loop executes.

What the code *should* do is increment the value stored at the location of the iterator inside the loop, so we need to dereference it.

```
(*iter)++
```

Answer (score 1):

It will sometimes pass the end of the array, yes.

If there's an even number of elements, you're lucky, as it will reach the halting condition. For an odd number of elements, you're invoking UB.

Answer (score 0):

`iter++` is the same as `std::advance(iter,1)` and moves the iterator forward to point to the next vector element. This is the same as `++iter`.

What you want is access the element that `iter` points to: use the `operator*` to access it:

```
++*iter; // or
(*iter)++;
```

Note that in your original post, your loop could never end if there is an odd number of items in your vector.

Comment: "could never end" - It might, it might not. Whether the loop ended depends upon the undefined behavior of both `iter++` and `iter != end()` when `iter` is out of range. It is more accurate to say, "might never end" or "invokes undefined behavior".